# Trouble with a small php function Http Error 500

Tags: php, http

I'm just learning php, To practice i want to try and make a php function that can generate CSS3 gradients easily in a document.

I am running into HTTP Error 500. here's the code :

```
<?php
function cgrad($c1,$c2,$applyto)
{
echo 
"<style type="text/css">
$applyto {
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, $c1 0%, $c2 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, $c1 0%, $c2 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, $c1 0%, $c2 100%); 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, $c1), color-stop(1, $c2));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, $c1 0%, $c2 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, $c1 0%, $c2 100%);
height : 100%;
width : 100%;}
</style>";
};
?>
<html>
<head>
<?php
cgrad(#FFFFFF,#000000,body);
?>
</head>
<body>
testing
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: HTTP 500 can occur when there are syntax errors in PHP. For future refernce, always check your code for ending semicolons, proper quotes, and things of that nature.

Comment: Thanks very much to both people who responded, Sorry about it being such a simple problem, Being new to php i didn't notice it.
Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo 
"<style type="text/css">
```

You can't put double quotes inside double quotes.  You can either escape them (like the other answers say) or use single quotes.

```
echo 
"<style type='text/css'>
```

Also, you need quotes when calling `cgrad`.

```
<?php
cgrad('#FFFFFF','#000000','body');
?>
```

Comment: The `cgrad` function's parameters need to be quoted because the pound `#` creates a comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 
"<style type="text/css">
```

You're using quotes both to delimit your echo statement, and inside it - PHP can't figure out what quotes are which. One way is to escape the quotes inside the echo statement:

```
echo 
"<style type=\"text/css\">
```